# Short Rounds Up?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Percentage Calculator running like so:

`(Current Progress Integer ÷ Max Progress Integer) x 100`

Here's an example:

`(1273 ÷ 1274) x 100` which results as `99.9215071` but when I do .ToString into a Label it outputs as `100` when obviously it isn't. It seems to be Rounding Up which I don't want.

How can I get around this and post it as `99`

Comment: Floor? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Integer number when divided by another integer number doesn't produce a decimal value but still an integer (or short)

Comment: Can you show the actual code - it is usually of some importance in coding issues

Comment: The Duplicate Question solves my issues. Thanks.

Comment: Probably another issue related to not having Option Strict On

Comment: @Steve - That depends on if you use the normal division operator (/) or the integer division operator (\\).